# Need help for dynamic calculation in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a table tab_1 with below values.

```
ID Calculation value
1                10
2                10
3    1+2         
4                 5
5    3-2          
6    5+1
```

Need help writing the query for following logic. I have a table where the records contain either calculation strings or values to be used in calculations. I need to parse the `calculation` like this:

```
ID 3 is the sum of ID 1 and 2.
ID 5 is the minus of ID 3 and 2.
ID 6 is the sum of ID 5 and 1.
```

Then I need to select the records for the referenced IDs  and perform the calculations. My 
expected output:

```
ID Calculation value
3    1+2         20
5    3-2         10
6    5+1         20
```

Thanks -- nani

Comment: use case statement

Comment: Can you provide the expected result. I could help to find the query

Comment: @ViKiNG - and exactly how would a CASE statement help solve this problem?

Comment: @APC.. sorry for late reply.  Case means as superuser had already suggested in his answer below? I was thinking on these lines too.

Comment: @viking - unfortunately superuser's answer renders the business rules rather than producing the output the OP actually wants.

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Comment: Is it always exactly two two operands? Then it would be way better to store id1, operator, and id2 in separate columns rather than in one string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Need help writing the query for below logic."

This is not a problem which can be solved in pure SQL, because:

- executing the calculation string requires dynamic SQL
- you need recursion to look up records and evaluate the results

Here is a recursive function which produces the answers you expect. It has three private procs so that the main body of the function is simple to understand. In pseudo-code:

1. look up record
2. if record is `value` then return it and exit
3. else explode `calculation`
4. recurse 1, 3, 4 for each part of exploded `calculation` until 2

Apologies for the need to scroll:

```
create or replace function dyn_calc
     (p_id in number)
      return number
is 
    result number;
    n1 number;
    n2 number;
    l_rec t23%rowtype;
    l_val number;

    type split_calc_r is record (
        val1 number
        , operator varchar2(1)
        , val2 number
    );
    l_calc_rec split_calc_r;

    function get_rec
        (p_id in number)
        return t23%rowtype
    is 
        rv t23%rowtype;
    begin
        select *
        into rv   
        from t23
        where id = p_id;
        return rv;
    end get_rec;    

    procedure split_calc
       (p_calc in varchar2
        , p_n1 out number
        , p_n2 out number
        , p_operator out varchar2)
    is
    begin
         p_n1 := regexp_substr(p_calc, '[0-9]+', 1, 1);
         p_n2 := regexp_substr(p_calc, '[0-9]+', 1, 2);
         p_operator := translate(p_calc, '-+*%01923456789','-+*%'); --regexp_substr(p_calc, '[\-\+\*\%]', 1, 1);
    end split_calc;

    function exec_calc 
        (p_n1 in number
          , p_n2 in number
          , p_operator in varchar2)
        return number
    is 
        rv number;
    begin
        execute immediate
            'select :n1 ' ||  p_operator ||  ' :n2 from dual'
            into rv
            using p_n1, p_n2; 
        return rv;
    end exec_calc;    

begin
    l_rec := get_rec(p_id);

    if l_rec.value is not null then
        result := l_rec.value;
    else        
         split_calc(l_rec.calculation
                     , l_calc_rec.val1
                     , l_calc_rec.val2
                     , l_calc_rec.operator);
         n1 := dyn_calc (l_calc_rec.val1);
         n2 := dyn_calc (l_calc_rec.val2);
         result := exec_calc(n1, n2, l_calc_rec.operator);
    end if;

    return result;
end;
/
```

Run like this:

```
SQL>  select dyn_calc(6) from dual;

DYN_CALC(6)
-----------
20

SQL>
```

or, to get the output exactly as you require:

```
select id, calculation, dyn_calc(id) as value
from t23
where calculation is not null;
```

**Notes**

- There is no exception handling. If the data is invalid the function will just blow up
- the `split_calc()` proc uses `translate()` to extract the operator rather than regex. This is because `regexp_substr(p_calc, '[\-\+\*\%]', 1, 1)` mysteriously swallows the `-`. This appears to be an environment-related bug. Consequently extending this function to process `1+4+2` will be awkward.

Here is [a LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f4by09m6mdklqspt3w59542fc).

Comment: @viking Thanks. It was one of those things that once I'd wrestled with it for fifteen minutes I had to see it through to the end. I don't get much chance to use recursion in my day job, so this was a welcome exercise.

Answer (score 1):

**In SQL:**

```
select 'ID ' +ID+ ' is the ' + case when calculation like '%-%' then ' minus '
when calculation like '%+%' then ' sum ' END +' of  
ID'+replace(replace(calculation,'+',' and '),'-',' and ')
from tab_1
where calculation is not null
```

**In Oracle:**

```
select 'ID ' ||ID|| ' is the ' || case when calculation like '%-%' then ' minus '
when calculation like '%+%' then ' sum ' END|| ' of 
ID'||replace(replace(calculation,'+',' and '),'-',' and ')
from tab_1
where calculation is not null
```

Comment: Thank you sqluser. Incase of ID 5 and 6 this sql is not working.

Comment: I just typed without checking it on my SQL . Let me try and paste the exact query for you

Comment: Query

select 'ID ' +cast(ID as varchar(10))+ ' is the' + case when calculation like '%-%' then ' minus ' when calculation like '%+%' then ' sum ' END +' of ID '+replace(replace(calculation,'+',' and '),'-',' and ') value from test.tab1 where calculation is not null
and calculation<>''


OUTPUT-

value
ID 3 is the sum  of ID 1 and 2
ID 5 is the minus  of ID 3 and 2
ID 6 is the sum  of ID 5 and 1

Comment: Thank you, Sorry for the confusion. Added expected output.

Comment: Your "IN SQL" part is wrong. First because Oracle _uses_ "SQL" and secondly because in "SQL" (the query language) the string concatenation operator is `||` not `+`

Comment: Regardless of whether the code runs it will produce the wrong answer. This just renders the business rules from the question whereas the OP wants some SQL to actually **produce the result** by looking up the values and executing the calculation.